# Emacs: delete forward/backward until a capital letter

Tags: emacs

I am trying to add some custom functions in emacs to deal with the situation where, for example, I want to delete the sub-string "Apple" in "TallAppleTree". I figure I need something like:

```
(defun delete-forward-to-cap ()
  (interactive)
  (delete-region (point) (save-excursion (skip-syntax-forward "???") (point))))
```

and

```
(defun delete-backward-to-cap ()
  (interactive)
  (delete-region (point) (save-excursion (skip-syntax-backward "???") (point))))
```

The forward one is a little more complicated. When the cursor is in between l and A, the search need to skip the first capital letter (to get rid of "Apple"). I am stuck at the parts marked "???". What should I put in there?

Answer (score 0):

Silly me have found a solution.

```
(defun delete-backward-to-cap ()
  (interactive)
  (progn
    (delete-region (point) (save-excursion (skip-chars-backward "a-z") (point)))
    (delete-backward-char 1)))
```

and

```
(defun delete-forward-to-cap ()
  (interactive)
  (progn
    (delete-forward-char 1)
    (delete-region (point) (save-excursion (skip-chars-forward "a-z") (point)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete the sub-string between the point and the next capital letter, you can use the skip-syntax-forward function with the "w" syntax class. The "w" syntax class matches any word constituent character, which includes letters, digits, and underscores. So the skip-syntax-forward function will skip over any letters, digits, and underscores until it reaches the next capital letter.

Here's how you can use the skip-syntax-forward function in your delete-forward-to-cap function:

```
(defun delete-forward-to-cap ()
  (interactive)
  (delete-region (point) (save-excursion (skip-syntax-forward "w") (point))))
```

Similarly, to delete the sub-string between the point and the previous capital letter, you can use the skip-syntax-backward function with the "w" syntax class. Here's how you can use the skip-syntax-backward function in your delete-backward-to-cap function:

```
(defun delete-backward-to-cap ()
  (interactive)
  (delete-region (point) (save-excursion (skip-syntax-backward "w") (point))))
```